# Batch file to modify all Mozilla FireFox profiles

Tags: batch-file, firefox

I would like to modify all FireFox profiles with a batch file but I can't make it work, it will modify only the default profile.

```
@Echo off
taskkill /im firefox.exe* /f
if exist "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*." (GOTO TRT) ELSE (GOTO END)
:TRT
cd  "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*."
echo user_pref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", ".tests"); >>prefs.js
:END
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that as easy as you are trying to...

You have to loop over the directory and repeat the steps in that way:

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /IM firefox.exe
if exist "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\" Goto :trt
Goto :eof
:trt
cd "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\"
for /d %%a in (*) do (
pushd %%a
if exist "prefs.js" (
echo( >> prefs.js
echo user_pref("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", ".tests"); >> prefs.js
)
popd
)
```

<del>Not tested though...</del>

Explanation:

As you already did, closes all instances of `firefox.exe`.
`IF` the Profile folder exists, go on further. `:eof` is an invisible label and marks the `e`nd `o`f `f`ile.
Changes the current directory into the profile folder.
`for` each `/d`irectory `in (*)`(=all) `do`

- `Push` the path to the single profile folder onto a stack and change to it
- check if the file `prefs.js` exists and echoes one safety new line and your value in there if it does.
- `Pop` the path from the stack and go back to the Profile folder

An addition: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of stackoverflow :)

Comment: Indeed a mistake on my end. I was not thinking straight and as said it has not been tested. I updated the code and the explanation and tested it now.